# How to remedy web audio time relationship w/ setTimeout if still bad on FireFox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am creating a music sequencing app and [I used the methodology explained in this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/scheduling/). However when I play my project in Chrome all is fine, when I use Firefox the timing is erratic and semi analogous to using setTimeout or SetInterval stand alone.

My scheduler code is below. [The JS file can be viewed here](http://helpknow.com/timing_test/combined/javascript/index.js). The working app can be viewed by going to the same link as the js file and replacing  "javascript/index.js" with "index.html" ( Stackoverflow won't let me post that url directly ).

[A JSfiddle is available here](http://jsfiddle.net/r85qjntz/2/)

If you listen in Chrome and then Firefox you can hear the difference, the latter is not good. I am not sure if this is my fault or just the way Firefox is.

```
function scheduleFutureNote() {
    while (futureNote <= audioContext.currentTime + 0.10) { //_________When you've gotten within a Nth of a second is when you schedule the note
        playFutureNote(futureNote);
        futureNote += (60 / tempo) / 4;
    }

    if (timer) {

        timer = window.setTimeout(scheduleFutureNote, 0.10); //__________sleep for n milliseconds...then check to see if we're close to next note.
    } else {
        timer === false
    }
};
```

Comment: This might be due to some laggy processes. Do you have anything else running on FF? (Add-ons, an other page requesting high resources,… ?) Maybe you can try [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) instead of setTimeout. –  Which is, after reading the given article the third and last solution the author gave for timing

Comment: I think I should try and figure out what is wrong before refactoring to use requestAnimationFrame as it should work ( better than it does) as is

Comment: well IMHO the wrong part is how setTimeout is handled by browsers. That's why they have built requestAnimationFrame()

Answer (score 1):

window.setTimeout() is in MILLISECONDS, not seconds.  You need to setTimeout( scheduleFutureNode, 100).

Comment: When I changed it to reflect your answer it makes the timing worse and extends the bad timing to chrome.

Comment: Your code snippet above doesn't have enough context to tell what's going on; the general approach should work on Firefox, of course (the metronome demo does).  Your code project isn't available at the referenced URL anymore.

Comment: Sorry about that. I fixed it and the code is now viewable in the url.I'll go ahead and create a jsfiddle as well albeit it will be a bit bloated and non working since it uses audio buffers. Thanks for taking the time. http://jsfiddle.net/r85qjntz/2/

Comment: Ah.  Yeah, the problem is that you're not passing the start time (the "time" parameter to your playFutureNote() method in to your checkIfRecordedAndPlay() method calls (and then in to your .play() calls on the sounds).

Comment: Remember, what you're trying to do is pre-SCHEDULE the starts of those buffers; they're supposed to actually START at some point in the future (over the next 100ms or so).  Your current code just gets called every 100ms (or would, if you changed the param as above), and then sets up any sound start()s for the proper time in the next 100ms.  Your current code checks for any starts that should occur in the next 100ms, and then IMMEDIATELY start()s that sound.

Comment: I think the reason it was working in Chrome before is that we probably aren't throttling your sub-millisecond calls into setTimeout; so you're calling your callback a TON - (every millisecond, or however often it can) - so the sounds are start()ed at "roughly" consistent intervals.  In Firefox, they're probably throttling, so the intervals aren't consistently lining up with the note starts.

Comment: I tried to decipher what you just said and modify the code accordingly but it simply breaks everything. Is there an example you could post  what I could change to make it work correctly ?

Comment: I put the 'time' argument in checkIfRecordedAndPlay and then I modified my buffer sound loader to have an argument that sets the start time and I placed the 'time' argument in the invoked sound function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66616/discussion-between-taoistwa-and-cwilso).